# How to raise a signal inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, signals

I have wrote a script to do some backup. There is a `if` block to ask confirmation:

```
read -p "Do you want to continue? [y/n]" confirm

if [[ ${confirm} == "n" ]]; then
    # do something like CTRL+Z, and halt until I run fg <job number> to activate this script
else
    # do some stuff
fi
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `kill -STOP $$`, or in `bash` you can use the `suspend` command.